# How to enable TLSv1.3 in jdk 8 by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, tls1.3

How to configure TLSv1.3 in java spring application?
Jdk 8 support 1.3 version of TLS and also has the backward compatibility.
Can anyone please help?